# How to forcefully grant permissions in android powered embedded devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am developing an android application which runs on android `powered board`(Not phones or tablets). This board has an `LED display`(No touch inputs), So I am  unable to grant permissions.
How can I grant permissions for these kind of android `powered embedded` devices?

Comment: Are you able to connect a mouse/keyboard through USB?

Comment: @Chris623 Yes, I can connect a USB mouse.